# Is there a way to turn on the function key indicator based on capslock status on Lenovo ThinkPad Yoga?

Tags: keyboard, thinkpad, capslock

The <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key comes with no LED indicator light on newer ThinkPad models. The <kbd>Fn</kbd> key has a light for when `FnLk` (function lock) is turned on (as if that's more important that the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key‽). The only caps lock indication is software-based: a symbol is shown on the screen.

And if you install a Linux distribution the chances are that such software won't be available out of the box. An LED light like the rest of the world puts on their keyboard would be so nice.

Can any of the LED lights be somehow made to toggle with the state of caps lock?

Comment: ust a thought but what if you swapped the 2 keys? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107566/how-to-swap-ctrl-and-capslock-using-xmodmap. Once swapped I would look at making the capslock key then send the Fn key scancode.

Comment: @slm That'd be awesome if I could do that. I probably won't do it until sometime after I'm graduate after this semester, in May.