# How to remap Caps_Lock to F12?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I tried these:

1. First I tried with `xmodmap`

   `clear Lock`

   `keycode  66 = F12`

but the issue is that it would reset my custom mapping after every reboot or log out. Therefore I had to run the command `xmodamp ~/.Xmodmap` every single time after reboot or log out. Trying to automate doesn't help either because  `xmodamp ~/.Xmodmap` would take like 10 seconds in order to run and during that time the whole computer is block, i.e. I could not switch to or use any other program.

Also I heard using xmodmap isn't really recommended.

2. The next thing I tried was setting <kbd>F12</kbd> in the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc`. I tried something like this:
   `key <CAPS> {»-[ F12»»-]»};` (<-- the  `»` symbol represents `tabs` on my computer). But that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Is there a way to permanently remap the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to the function key <kbd>F12</kbd>?

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107566/how-to-swap-ctrl-and-capslock-using-xmodmap/107568#107568.

Comment: @slm From my understanding, your links provides information of how to remap the `Caps_Lock` with keys like `Alt`, `Ctrl_R`, `Ctrl_L`, etc. But they don't tell me how to remap to `F12`. Using `xev` doesn't help me either. I tried to set `F12` with `keycode 96` and `Oxffc9` in `xmodmap`. But it didn't help.

Comment: Take a look at this one then - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49650/how-to-get-keycodes-for-xmodmap. Search the site for 'remap key' we have a lot of these Q&A's already solved, you're not doing anything new here from the collection of other Q's IMO, except for the key choices 8-).

Comment: @slm I looked already. The problem is that remapping Caps_Lock is not your ordinary use case. Also I mentioned the issues with using xmodmap, i.e. it resets after reboot and log out; takes too long to load - thus not feasible for automation; not really recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I've been struggling with exactly the same issue.

To me the problem seems to be either something overwrites the `xmodmap` setting (for instance, `setxkbmap` will do that, so make sure, if it's a part of your `.Xmodmap` to use it before the `xmodmap` command), or it is not run.

My `.xinitrc` clearly looks like it should run my `.Xmodmap`...

What does your setup look like?

I'm using i3 and I have what I'd call a workaround now, by running `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` in my i3-config file, which works. I don't like this solution because if I use my Plasma setup, CapsLock will be back to normal.

My `.Xmodmap` looks like this:

```
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
keysym Caps_Lock = F12
```

I don't think I have your issue of `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` taking a long time.

I hope we can find a solution, let me know if you do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Following this answer worked for me: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170357/105061

I'm paraphrasing it here for completeness:

1. Run `sudo evtest` to find

- The keyboard **bus**, **vendor**, and **product**. Look for a line similar to this:

```
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x46d product 0xc31c version 0x110
```

- The **scancode** of the key you want to change. Press the key and note the value after `(MSC_SCAN)`.

```
Event: time 1678720211.060421, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70039
```

2. Create a file with the remapping, in `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/98-custom-keyboard.hwdb`. Be careful to convert the identifiers to uppercase so that they can be discerned from the delimeters `b`, `v`, and `p`. The key name should be lowercase. My file ended up looking like this:

```
evdev:input:b0003v046DpC31C*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_70039=f12       # capslock to f12
```

3. Rebuild the database with `sudo udevadm hwdb --update`.
4. Apply the settings with `sudo udevadm trigger --sysname-match="event*"`.
5. Optionally, run `sudo evtest` again to verify that it works.